# Is vacuum polarization the medium of propagation of EM waves?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, quantum-electrodynamics

Since the electric and magnetic fields are produced by charged particles, is it correct to think that light travels trough a medium consisting in this particle-antiparticle pairs from vacuum polarization?

If so does that mean that light doesn't really travel in vacuum, but rather is the byproduct of the interactions beetwen this particle-antiparticle pairs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are thinking in a loop such as a $\,\,\gamma \rightarrow e^+ + e^- \rightarrow \gamma \,\,$ kind of in-flight pair production or fluctuation, in QED this does not change or affect $\,c \,$ even after renormalization. It is also a second order effect, the main effect is just photons existing in the vacuum and since they remain massless then they have no other kinetic response other than moving at $\,c\,$ due to special relativity. Instead of "travel" you might want to think as light connecting events separated by a null 4-dimensional interval $(\Delta s)^2 =0.$ Which we experience as traveling at speed $c.$ So, light does not move because of these interactions or fluctuations, it moves because has zero mass and that is the structure of space-time.

All the above is not in contradiction with the fact that the QED vacuum is a sort of material since quantum fluctuations affect both the magnetic permeability  and electric permittivity but this is not to add or change the speed of light. And  it is not equivalent to adding an effective mass to the photon as happens inside matter (which explains $v < c$ in matter) and does not change the fact that light *has* to move in the vacuum. This is rather ingrained in QED.